# Upload user photo in the frontend - wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, file-upload, frontend, avatar

I'm trying to create something that will replace the user avatar in the admin back-end, with a front-end upload system that will save the uploaded photo to specific user.

How do i begin?

Comment: There is a plugin called user-photo which I have used previously. I would have a look at using this and also maybe using theme my login to allow customers to access their profiles. Then by placing the upload form in the profile, you should be able to succeed in allowing people to upload their photos via the front end once they have logged in

Answer (score 2):

You can go through these sample links to find out what to choose or at least understand how to begin:

http://wp.tutsplus.com/tutorials/allow-users-to-submit-images-your-site/

https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/82291/creating-front-end-image-uploader-that-uploads-images-as-posts

http://wordpress.org/plugins/frontend-uploader/